# How to make an image not overlap navigation bar in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

So what I am trying to do is the same effect on http://www.spine-practice.com/index.php where the photo overlaps the navigation bar which I have done though there is one problem.

On theirs how did they make it so that you can actually click the navigation bar correctly instead of the picture blocking you from being able to?

Comment: Can you show use *yours* though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to mess around with the `z-index` property.

Comment: This was the trick. Through making a separate navigation bar class I was able to use my original navigation class and have a z-index of 0 and then on my class of the navigation bar setting one higher than the image which resulted in it working.