# How to create dropdown box that displays text information?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm creating an faq page and I want to have a dropdown list that has all of the frequently asked questions and when pressed they display a different answer. Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

When the user selects a question from 1 they are displayed the answer to that question in area 2.

How do I make this so that it stays on the same page and does not completely load a new html page?

Comment: I find it rather strange that all answers with solutions after your last one in 2013 http://stackoverflow.com/q/19164610/ stopped being accepted. So, what happened?

Comment: Not to mention that this question is no different than the question you asked a few days ago that got closed for lack of details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667492/how-to-make-dropdown-menu-that-only-loads-the-text-not-whole-new-page This is not a code writing or tutorial service

Comment: Well use AJAX that will help you load content dynamically without reload.
This [Old Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839988/load-php-content-with-jquery-ajax)  may help you with what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide your answers by default. Match the value of the select options with the ID's of individual answers. Monitor the `change` event of the select, and on `change`, show the ID associated with the selected option value.

```js
$('select').on('change',function() {
  var answer = $(this).val();
  $('.answers').hide();
  $('#'+answer).show();
})
```

```css
.answers {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option disabled selected>choose</option>
  <option value="answer1">answer1</option>
  <option value="answer2">answer2</option>
  <option value="answer3">answer3</option>
</select>

<div class="answers" id="answer1">
  answer1
</div>
<div class="answers" id="answer2">
  answer2
</div>
<div class="answers" id="answer3">
  answer3
</div>
```